# LATEX - How to write \lstdefinestyle fort the YAML language

Tags: latex, listings

How can I create a **\lstdefinestyle** for the YAML programming language using the LISTINGS package?
Thank you

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/654987/36296

Comment: I already had that answer, I was looking for something more specific. In particular when:
- nodeSelector:
nodeSelector must be colored blue and not black. Thank you